# FTDI differences between VCP and D2XX

Tags: ftdi, d2xx

I have a FTDI FT232R device and am currently trying to figure out whether to use VCP or D2XX. I've read a little about the pros and cons of both, but am still unable to determine which one to use for this project. Since I am going to use Linux for this project, is it even worth the extra effort to use D2XX? Any kind of help or information would be appreciated.

Greetings,
Sparkas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here what I understood from some reading and experience. This list is not exhaustive and I hope that I will be able to improve it with the community answers.

## VCP

Pros:

- Built-in inside the Linux kernel

Cons:

- Slower than D2XX? I've being using an FTDI device and its documentation said that there where not using the VCP method because the driver was too slow.

## D2XX:

Pros:

- More features: For instance one could use the `FT_ListDevices()` function to get the list of FTDI enabled devices. This function is not available using VCP.

Cons:

- You have to embed the FTDI library inside the project

VCP: Is the virtual com port which appear as the legacy comm port port like /dev/ttyUSB0.
D2XX interface is the proprietary interface for the FTDI devices.
D2XX gives much more access to the hardware which are not available by the VCP.
Like working in different mode . Asynchronous , synchronous mode or bit bang mode or writing to the eeprom chip.

## References:

- http://www.dlpdesign.com/tnt/VCP%20Vs%20D2XX.pdf
- http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/ftdi-high-baudrate